# is there some FHIR test server with continious integration http://hl7-fhir.github.io/ release?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We want to make some proofs with new resource commits on http://hl7-fhir.github.io/. is there some available fhir server for testing?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Also, is there some new FhirJavaReferenceClient for FHIR Continuous integration release?

Answer (score 2):

The only public server that is tracking the development version is http://fhir-dev.healthintersections.com.au

It's fallen behind in the last few weeks. It's my goal to have it catch up by Dec 7.

Comment: thanks. we will introduce change in our very alpha server until Dec 7. and in that moment, client development will continue with your server. Thanks in advance