# Building a FHIR Server on an Existing Application: Step-by-Step Guide

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are trying to build a FHIR server as a facade to an existing EHR.  We are following the instructions in the paper by Robert Worden dated Dec 2013 "Building a FHIR Server on an Existing Application: Step-by-Step Guide".  The backend mappping tool from www.OpenMapSW.com  does not seem to work.  We can connect to the database, but the tool is not able to browse the content (i.e. cannot display tables, etc, so we cannot do any mapping).  Any help, insights, would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but your question does not seem to meet the [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question check list as you provide no error messages or facts needed to reproduce the problem. Open-ended "_any insights_" questions are not on-topic. `Grahame Grieve` in answer to question [is there some FHIR test server with continious integration http://hl7-fhir.github.io/ release?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27031033/2626313) says he's running the "the only public server that is tracking the development version". Turning your attention over there may bring some fruits

Comment: Also, the spec has changed a lot since the end of 2013, so you probably want to find something newer to follow.

Comment: Yes to the 2 above comments.

You will need to make lots of decisions when you do this, including; which version(s) of FHIR do you plan to support, what approach to searching/indexing, can you support histories, should you sync content to a FHIR server and remove the constraints of the legacy, what load/performance considerations should be considered?

And what platform are you developing on, there are existing reference implementations on [.NET](https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api) and java [HAPI](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir) that can assist greatly here.

Comment: And I forgot about the [Furore Spark server](https://github.com/furore-fhir/spark) in .NET that has a MongoDB at the back, but it does have an assembly in it that does a lot of the plumbing that you would otherwise need to write yourself (and uses the above mentioned .net fhir client too).